# Google Calendar Chart click date and redirect page with date in URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-visualization

How to add a link on Google Calendar Charts? I want to make the dates clickable and when I click it, the page will be redirected and the date where I clicked should be in the URL. So I'm expecting a link like this. [mypage.php?date=2019-02-21](http://thispage.php?date=2019-02-21)

Here is my Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
       var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
       dataTable.addRows([
        <?php
            $show=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM event");
            while($found=mysqli_fetch_array($show)){ 
                $event_id = $found['event_id'];
                $event_date = $found['event_date'];

                $sd = date_parse_from_format("Y-n-d", $event_date);
                $year = $sd["year"];
                $month = $sd["month"] - 1;
                $day = $sd["day"];  

                    $febs=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE event_date = '$event_date'");
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($febs);
                    $counts = $row[0];

        ?>

          [ new Date(<?php echo $year; ?>, <?php echo $month; ?>, <?php echo $day; ?>),  <?php echo $counts; ?> ],

        <?php } ?>
        ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

         var options = {
                 title: "EVENTS CALENDAR PLOT",
                 height: 350,
                 noDataPattern: {
                   backgroundColor: '#75f990',
                   color: '#00ff34'
                 }
               };

       chart.draw(dataTable, options);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the chart's `'select'` event to know which date the user has clicked.
use a date formatter to format the date selected and open the url.

```
var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
  pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
});
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    window.open('http://thispage.php/?date=' + formatDate.formatValue(new Date(selection[0].date)));
  }
});
```

see following working snippet,
for example purposes, the url is written to the console...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['calendar']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [new Date(), 1]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

  var options = {
    title: 'EVENTS CALENDAR PLOT',
    height: 350,
    noDataPattern: {
      backgroundColor: '#75f990',
      color: '#00ff34'
    }
  };

  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
  });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      //window.open('http://thispage.php/?date=' + formatDate.formatValue(new Date(selection[0].date)));
      console.log('http://thispage.php/?date=' + formatDate.formatValue(new Date(selection[0].date)));
    }
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar_basic"></div>
```